Programmatically creating Excel file suddenly failing
I have a project that's been running for 15 years that is suddenly giving an error when trying to create an Excel file on both my local machine and my user's machine at their office.  To test, I've created a new project (Windows 10, Windows Forms, .Net Framework 4.7.2), installed the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel NuGet package, added a button to a form and in the click event, set the value of a cell to "Hello World" and I'm still getting the error.  I can't find anything online about this error either outside of suggestions to repair Excel which I've already done to no avail.
Here's the error:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND)).'

And here's the vb.net code:
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application()
Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add() ' fails on this line
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWb.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

xlSheet.Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "hello world!"

xlApp.Workbooks(1).SaveAs("testing.xls")

xlApp.Visible = True

All of the above is with Option Strict On
If I make another project, leave Option Strict Off, don't download the NuGet package and use the below code, I don't have any issue
Dim xlApp As Object = Nothing
Dim xlBook As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object

xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible = False
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)

xlSheet.Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Hello world!"

xlApp.Visible = True


I've seen it mentioned that a Quick repair worked where a full repair didn't. However, you probably already suspect that using a Nuget package to create Excel documents will be more reliable.

@Andrew Morton The Quick Repair worked.  I tried this earlier but under Apps and Features I don't have a Modify option like everyone was describing.  Instead I went to Advanced Options and clicked repair there which apparently is something different.  Once I launched the repair tool from the command line, the Quick Repair option worked.

installed the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel NuGet package: MS doesn't have a Nuget package for Interop Excel. Also, if one looks at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Nuget package it states: This is entirely unsupported...

The interop library you need is specific to the exact version of Office running on the user's computer. If either of these is out of line, things break. (Makes it... interesting... shipping this kind of thing to the general public that might have any or no Office version). Also, avoid saving the old .xls files (the newer xlsx will be old enough to vote in January)

The following may be of interest: Early and Late Binding (Visual Basic)

I haven't done Office interop for a while, but my experience is that it is best to first develop with early-binding using the libraries (so you get the help and autocomplete), but then switch it all to late-binding for deployment. The reason is that the libraries are locked to a particular version of Excel, while late-binding will work for most versions.
